# Replacing android debug key with android release key

Tags: android, key, release, signing

Hi i am newbie to android. I have an android apk signed with debug key.Now my key has expired so i have renewed my key and i have release key. The issue is that i could not update my existing application with the new release key.if i try to replace the existing one(signed with debugger key) with the new one i am getting error "Application not installed". What is the solution or workaround to this issue? I tried uninstalling the old one and installing the new one. It works fine but i want the new app to be replaced. Pls help. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't reinstall an application signed with different key. As you said, you have to uninstall the old one first and install it again signed with the new key.

From android [docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#strategies):

> Application upgrade – As you release updates to your application, you
>   will want to continue to sign the updates with the same certificate or
>   set of certificates, if you want users to upgrade seamlessly to the
>   new version. When the system is installing an update to an
>   application, it compares the certificate(s) in the new version with
>   those in the existing version. If the certificates match exactly,
>   including both the certificate data and order, then the system allows
>   the update. If you sign the new version without using matching
>   certificates, you will also need to assign a different package name to
>   the application — in this case, the user installs the new version as a
>   completely new application.

Comment: Is there any workaround? because i have already released the app with debugger key. Now i want to update the app with release key. How could i do this?

Comment: You can change the package name and sign the apk with a release key. This will install a new app, but from then, the app will be updatable seamlessly. The other option is continue signing with the debug key :/

Comment: oh..:( then how to renew the existing debugging key without deleting it in order to extend the validity period(i want the same key without any change) ?

Comment: I think not. Anyway, if this would be possible, the key will be different, and the app certificates won't match, so the problem will be the same as if you use your release key.

Comment: oh..ok. Could i get the existing expired debugger key used for signing? so that i can extend the same and renew it with the extended validity period.

Comment: Maybe you can. But you will need the same debug.keystore used to generate the APK. You can probably find it at folder ´.android´ in your `HOME` directory. Please, read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html), you will find useful information related to this stuff and how to generate certificates with `keytool`.

Comment: Check out this blog post: http://androidbook.blogspot.com.es/2009/11/tip-dealing-with-expired-debug.html

Comment: how to get the existing certificate or key using the key tool?